# Should a contractor who uses subcontractors carry workers' compensation insurance?

Tags: contractors

I'm in the process of hiring a contractor in California for a small masonry project (retaining wall, budget <$20k). I found a contractor I like, with good recommendations and a competitive bid. He is a "general contractor" and will hire a sub and oversee the project. Our contract will be with him.

I checked out his contractor license with the [State License Board website](https://www.cslb.ca.gov/onlineservices/checklicenseII/checklicense.aspx) and everything looks good - his bond is current, his classification is "B - GENERAL BUILDING" which sounds appropriate, and there are no complaints or other issues.

Under "workers' compensation", it says:
*This license is exempt from having workers compensation insurance; they certified that they have no employees at this time.*

As far as I know this is true, he has no employees. BUT he will be hiring a subcontractor for this job. Does this mean he should have workers' compensation insurance? If the subcontractor carries their own insurance, would that be sufficient? Is this something I should be concerned about, or is this normal?

Comment: Check with a lawyer in your area - what is relevant in my area won’t count.

Comment: There may be some answers that apply to most jobs in most places.  Confining this to the USA helps a lot.  But there are significant differences in some states, counties, cities, industries, and jobs.  Statistics won't help you if your sub is an exception so get hyper-specific advice from a local expert.

Comment: @jay613 I didn't realize this was something that varied so much. I assumed the presence of a state license board meant it was standardized, at least within the state of California. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: The more regulated a job+location is, the more likely it is that businesses are responsible for social protections on subs.  California is fairly heavy on regulation, and if your industry is regulated there (ie there is a licensing board) ... you are more likely to have special requirements.   I'm not in California so don't credit me with any special wisdom.   I happen to know that NYC taxi owners can almost never avoid paying Comp insurance for drivers due to rules imposed by the taxi licensing authority even though drivers are rarely employees.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this gets into the weeds of workers' insurance and such

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question, not a home improvement question.   Try https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

**IANAL**, but as a *general* rule in the US (may vary by state...):

- A business does not need to have workmen's compensation insurance if they have no employees other than the owners. (Owners may be true employees - C corporation and paying themselves via W-2, or may not be - S corporation.)
- When a company pays someone to do a job, it can take essentially 3 forms:

  - W-2 - Regular employees. Need workmen's compensation - i.e., even if they didn't have any employees before, if they started hiring on a W-2 basis for your task then they *now* have employees, required to pay workmen's compensation, etc.
  - 1099 - Independent contractors. These are individual people (not other companies), who (essentially) work on a piecemeal as-needed basis (not "regular hours"), can work for multiple companies if they choose (not exclusive to one company), set their own hours within reason (obviously if there is a deadline and they don't get a task done they won't get called back for more work). There are some very specific IRS requirements to meet, but effectively they work for themselves and no workmen's compensation from the company paying them (not their employees) or from their own companies (since they are, generally, individuals or owners of their own small companies).
  - Other companies. No workmen's compensation from the company hiring them. These may pay *their* people via W-2 or 1099, etc. and the cycle continues. But if they don't pay via W-2, they are exempt again.

Subcontractors may be "1099" or may be other companies. Not your concern. FYI, there are times where a big company will *insist* on sending a 1099 to another company. But under current law (it could change...) the receiving company doesn't normally have to do anything with it. 1099s are a way for the IRS to make sure money is reported so that taxes will get paid on it. But if it goes to a company rather than an individual then it just gets lumped in with all other revenue and is not directly taxable.

So from the specific "workmen's compensation" issue, it really isn't, IMHO, your problem as a consumer. However, what **is** a real issue is **liability insurance**. For anything where there is a significant risk (i.e., nothing is 100% free of risk, but fixing a sink is very different from building an addition), requesting a certificate of *liability* insurance is worthwhile. That is what protects you should there be major damage - e.g., if a company is removing a tree, that's going to cover the tree falling on your house, on the contractor's people, the subcontractor's people or you & your family. That insurance will normally cover both property damage and medical expenses, but if there is workmen's compensation involved (e.g., W-2 real employee, not an owner, injured on the job) then the workemn's compensation policy will pay (the insurance companies have ways to work out the details).

Workmen's compensation insurance is a very specific thing - it covers on-the-job injuries to workers. It is important, but the overall liability is what you are really concerned about. There may simply be no legal requirement for workmen's compensation insurance at any level, and even if there is, that is a legal issue for the employer, not for you.

Comment: Great write-up. Also, it is not unreasonable for the project owner to request insurance certificates: liability from the general and subs, workers comp from those who are required to have it. A very careful project owner might confirm the liability insurance doesn't exclude the type of work being done (it happens far too often). Owner could even request to be listed as additional insured. On the other hand, if an owner has too many demands relative to the size of the project, a contractor who has lots of jobs available may just decline the project!